# why ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1573,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1573,2)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import os,time
import gc
import re
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def convert_dtype(x):
    if not x:
        return ''
    try:
        return str(x)   
    except:        
        return ''

def convert_int(x):
    if not x:
        return -1
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        try:
            return int(float(x))
        except:
            return -1

def convert_list(x):
    return eval(x)

def LoadData(filename):
    datatype = {
    #'uid' : convert_dtype,
    #'sourceIP_new': convert_dtype,
    #'destinationIP_new': convert_dtype,
    'sourcePort': convert_int,
    'destinationPort': convert_int,
    #'protocol': convert_int,
    'directionType': convert_int,
    'jumboPayloadFlag': convert_int,
    'packetSize': convert_int,
    #'detectName_md5': convert_dtype,
    #'attackType': convert_int,
    #'detectStart': convert_dtype,
    #'detectEnd': convert_dtype,
    #'orgIDX': convert_int,
    'eventCount': convert_int,
    'payload': convert_dtype,
    'normalized_bd': convert_list,
    'notasciistr' : convert_int,
    'length': convert_int,
    'analyResult': convert_int,
    }
    data = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=',',encoding = 'utf-8', converters=datatype,on_bad_lines='warn')
    return data

def LearningModel():
    savepath = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\TASK\\'
    datalist = os.listdir(savepath+'testlearning')
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    #bar = tqdm(total=len(datalist),position=0)
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=2022, warm_start=True)
    
    x_test = []
    y_test = []
    errorlog = []
    train_predict = []
    for file in datalist[3:]:

        print(file)
        f = '\\'.join([savepath+'feature',file])
        df = LoadData(f)
        normalized_bd = []

        X = df[['sourcePort', 'destinationPort' ,
                  'directionType' ,'jumboPayloadFlag' ,
                  'packetSize' ,'eventCount', 
                  'notasciistr','length']].values.tolist()
        np_nbd = df['normalized_bd']
        X_ =[]
        
        for (i,j) in zip(X,np_nbd):
            X_.append(i+j)

        X = np.array(X_)
 
        Y = df['analyResult']
       
  
        try:
            x_train, mini_x_test, y_train, mini_y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.1, shuffle = True, stratify = Y, random_state=2022)
        except:
            x_train, mini_x_test, y_train, mini_y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.1, shuffle = True, random_state=2022)
        
        rfc.fit(x_train,y_train)
        rfc.n_estimators += 1
        

        y_pred = rfc.predict(x_train)
        train_predict.append(accuracy_score(y_true = y_train, y_pred = y_pred))

        x_test += mini_x_test.tolist()
        y_test += mini_y_test.tolist()


        #bar.update()
        
    #bar.close()
    
    return rfc,x_test,y_test,train_predict

def PredictModel(rfc,x_test,y_test):
    print('learning!')
    y_pred = rfc.predict(x_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_true = np.array(y_test), y_pred = y_pred)
    print('Test set')
    print(f"정확도(accuracy):{acc:0.4f}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rfc,x_test,y_test,train_predict = LearningModel()
    print(train_predict)
    PredictModel(rfc,x_test,y_test)
```

#error log

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py:667, in _accumulate_prediction(predict, X, out, lock)
    665 with lock:
    666     if len(out) == 1:
--> 667         out[0] += prediction
    668     else:
    669         for i in range(len(out)):

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1573,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1573,2)
```

#X -> 264 numpy array , y -> label
#x_test[0]

```
[60006.0, 80.0, 1.0, 0.0, 289.0, 1.0, 0.0, 235.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0425531914893617, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0425531914893617, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05106382978723404, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00425531914893617, 0.00425531914893617, 0.00851063829787234, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02553191489361702, 0.02553191489361702, 0.02553191489361702, 0.01702127659574468, 0.01276595744680851, 0.00851063829787234, 0.0, 0.01702127659574468, 0.00425531914893617, 0.00851063829787234, 0.0, 0.00851063829787234, 0.00851063829787234, 0.03404255319148936, 0.00425531914893617, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01276595744680851, 0.0, 0.02553191489361702, 0.0, 0.00851063829787234, 0.00851063829787234, 0.0, 0.00851063829787234, 0.00425531914893617, 0.0, 0.00425531914893617, 0.00425531914893617, 0.00425531914893617, 0.0, 0.00425531914893617, 0.00851063829787234, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00425531914893617, 0.01702127659574468, 0.00425531914893617, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02553191489361702, 0.00425531914893617, 0.029787234042553193, 0.00425531914893617, 0.06808510638297872, 0.00851063829787234, 0.01276595744680851, 0.01276595744680851, 0.02553191489361702, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01702127659574468, 0.00851063829787234, 0.08936170212765958, 0.059574468085106386, 0.02553191489361702, 0.0, 0.02553191489361702, 0.02127659574468085, 0.07234042553191489, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01276595744680851, 0.00425531914893617, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

#y_test

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

X length is same Y length

when I execute code with just one file(causing problem) it works well. but execute with all file make error.
Please Help me.

Comment: Operative word is 'non-broadcastable'.  Likely, something is ending up a list or some `pandas` non-broadcastable object instead of a `numpy` array.

Comment: indent the error stack properly

Comment: The error says that in `out[0] += prediction`, `out` is (15...,1) shape, and `prediction` is (15...,2).  With '+=" it cannot change the shape of `out`.

Comment: thank you very much about your comments, check code and data again I guess there is something load data error, it makes rfc.predict problem;

Comment: large files(over 60GB) for machine learning is here, but my computer ram is (32gb). 
can you give some tips for how to learn ML model(random forest) with large file using mini batch, partial fit or one file by one ML model...